# Break distribution scheduling problem using time grains

Tags: optaplanner

I have a following time scheduling optimisation problem:

There are *n* breaks to be scheduled. A break takes up *k* time grains of 15 minutes each. The total horizon I am looking at is of *m* time grains. Each time grain has a desired amount of breaks to optimise for. The range to start a break at is defined per break, you cannot freely pick the range.

To make it more general - there is a distribution of breaks over time as a goal. I need to output a result which would align with this desired distribution as much as possible. I am allowed to move each break within certain boundaries, e.g. 1 hour boundary.

I had a look at the TimeGrain pattern as a starting point which is described here: https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/12/01/TimeSchedulingDesignPatterns.html and in this video: https://youtu.be/wLK2-4IGtWY. I am trying to use Constraint Streams for incremental optimisation.

My approach so far is following:

Break.scala:

```scala
case class Break(vehicleId: String, durationInGrains: Int)
```

TimeGrain.scala:

```scala
@PlanningEntity
case class TimeGrain(desiredBreaks: Int,
                     instant: Instant,
                     @CustomShadowVariable(...), // Dummy annotation, I want to use the entity in constraint stream 
                     var breaks: Set[Break])
```

BreakAssignment:

```scala
@PlanningEntity
case class BreakAssignment(
  break: Break,
  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = Array("timeGrainRange"))
  var startingTimeGrain: TimeGrain,
  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeGrainRange")
  @ProblemFactCollectionProperty @field
  timeGrainRange: java.util.List[TimeGrain],
  @CustomShadowVariable(
    variableListenerClass = classOf[StartingTimeGrainVariableListener],
    sources = Array(new PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "startingTimeGrain"))
  )
  var timeGrains: util.Set[TimeGrain]
)

object BreakAssignment {
  class StartingTimeGrainVariableListener extends VariableListener[Solution, BreakAssignment] {
    override def afterVariableChanged(scoreDirector: ScoreDirector[Solution], entity: BreakAssignment): Unit = {
      val end = entity.startingTimeGrain.instant
        .plusSeconds((entity.break.durationInGrains * TimeGrain.grainLength).toSeconds)
      scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution.timeGrains.asScala
        .filter(
          timeGrain =>
            timeGrain.instant == entity.startingTimeGrain.instant ||
            entity.startingTimeGrain.instant.isBefore(timeGrain.instant) && end
              .isAfter(timeGrain.instant)
        )
        .foreach { timeGrain =>
          scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(timeGrain, "breaks")
          timeGrain.breaks = timeGrain.breaks + entity.break
          scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(timeGrain, "breaks")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Constraints.scala:

```scala
private def constraint(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory) =
  constraintFactory
    .from(classOf[TimeGrain])
    .filter(timeGrain => timeGrain.breaks.nonEmpty)
    .penalize(
      "Constraint",
      HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
      (timeGrain: TimeGrain) => {
        math.abs(timeGrain.desiredBreaks - timeGrain.breaks.size)
      }
    )
```

As you can see I need to iterate over all the grains in order to find out which ones needs to be updated to hold the break which was just moved in time. This somewhat negates the idea of Constraint Streams.

A different way to look at the issue I am facing is that I cannot come up with an approach to link the BreakAssignment planning entity with respective TimeGrains via e.g. Shadow Variables. A break assignment is spanning multiple time grains. A time grain in return contains multiple break assignments. For the soft constraint I need to group all the assignments within the same grain, accessing the desired target break count of a grain, while doing this for all the grains of my time horizon. My approach therefore is having each grain as a planning entity, so I can store the information of all the breaks on each change of the starting time grain of the assignment himself. What I end up is basically a many-to-many relationship between assignments and time grains. This does not fit into the inverse mechanism of a shadow variable from my understanding as it needs to be a one-to-many relationship.

Am I going in the wrong direction while trying to come up with the correct model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly what you mean, then conceptually, in the TimeGrain class, I would keep a (custom) shadow variable keeping (only) the count of Break instances that are overlapping that TimeGrain (instance). Let me call it breakCount for simplicity. Let me call x the number of TimeGrains a Break spans.

So, upon the solver assigning a Break instance to a TimeGrain instance, I would increment that TimeGrain instance's breakCount. Not only thát TimeGrain instance's breakCount, but also the breakCount of the next few (x-1) TimeGrain instances. Beware to wrap each of those incrementations in a "scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged()"-"scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged()" bracket.

The score calculation would do the rest. But do note that I myself would moreover also *square* the difference of a TimeGrain's ideal breakCount and it's "real" breakCount (i.e. the shadow variable), like explained in OptaPlanner's documentation, in order to enforce more "fairness".

Edit : of course also *decrement* a TimeGrain's breakCount upon removing a Break instance from a Timegrain instance...

Comment: Thanks, I think I get your proposal of keeping a count, rather than a reference to the actual breaks, i.e. list of breaks which this TimeGrain includes. I like the idea - will try to implement, test it and will get back here to share if it worked as expected.

Comment: Don't forget (I made that mistake recently too) :every entity with a shadow variable becomes a PlanningEntity, so don't forget to annotate it that way. And moreover : don't forget to include all these (possibly new) PlanningEntity classes in the solver's cinfiguration.